# Xcode adds padding displayed after compilation

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I expose the elements along the axis, and after the compilation they are shifted.
How to fix?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6mVO.png)

Comment: Did you design for iPhone 6 in the storyboard? Did you add Layout Constraints ?

Comment: Seems like you are not setting constraints for the views. try to use this with setting constraints or disable auto layout & set relative position for each view

Comment: You have to add constraints to them. not just place them because maybe you are placing them in other device screen in storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set constraints to each of your elements. Set all four that tiny red switches.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCOZZ.png)